# Apache Solr which version to download 3.6.2 or 4.0, what is the main difference

Tags: apache, solr

There are 2 versions of Apache Solr on their official website 3.6.2 and 4.0:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/downloads.html

What is the main difference, how to choose one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get 4.0. It is a significant improvement over the 3.6.2 with a new Admin UI, support for lots of new options and a completely new SolrCloud distributed search mechanism.

If you are starting out, there is no point of going with the old.

The only thing is, 4.1 is about to be released. With a couple more improvements. So, download 4.0 today and 4.1 next week. Or just wait a couple of days and get it then.